# iCal4J Error: net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator <clinit>

Tags: java, ical4j

I'm sending an appointment to MS Outlook using iCal4J and it's working great, the appointment is going through. However my console is displaying the following:

```
Oct 24, 2013 9:53:57 AM net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator <clinit>
INFO: ical4j.properties not found.
```

The 'INFO' line I'm not worried about, its the `net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator` I'm concerned about. Can anybody elaborate on what this means. I don't think it's an exception cause it would have been cause in my `try...catch`.

During my research I found mentions of enabling `ConfigurationHints`, but I can't find examples of it.

Is the `net.fortuna.ical4j.util.Configurator` an error that I need to be concerned about and if so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ical4j is a crossplatform java library, it runs on android and on j2se.

i dont think that this is an error. it is just a once-per-run-info that the behavior of the lib can be configured (at least on non-android systems where the properties file can be outside the jar)

slf4a, a android compatible crossplatform logging abstraction layer, does the same: one message that no logging provider was found. This message is also intended for non-android apps where adding a slf4a-Xxxxx.jar to the java app allows logging. in android this makes no since because you cannot add the jar at runtime. but for non-android it makse sense ...